How to access a Function App that uses Microsoft as Identity Provider? Unauthorized after setup
I have an Azure Function App. It has a function that exposes an API. I want to access it in two ways:

From my own browser
In a Data Factory, in a MS Fabric workspace

The Function App has Microsoft as an identity provider, with the following settings:

Identity provider: Microsoft
App registration: SomeAppRegistration
Supported account types: Current tenant - Single tenant
Client secret setting name: MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET
Issuer URL: Blank
Allowed token audiences: https://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
Client application requirement: Allow requests from any application (Not recommended)
Identity requirement: Allow requests from any identity
Tenant requirement: Allow requests from specific tenants

Also, I have added the following Access Control (IAM) role assignment to the Function App:

Owner: my_own_email@email.com
Logic Apps Standard Reader: The Fabric Workspace (which is a Managed Identity)

In addition, the Function App has an App Registration in Entra ID (formely Active Directory (AAD)).
The Function has the following function.json:
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}

When attempting to access the API in the browser, I get redirected to ``, and the following error:
{"code":401,"message":"An error of type 'access_denied' occurred during the login process: 'AADSTS650056: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the following: the client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, the admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Or, check the certificate in the request to ensure it's valid. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant. Client app ID: XX. Trace ID: XX Correlation ID: XX Timestamp: XX'"}
When attempting to access the API in the Data Factory (Fabric Workspace), I get Unauthorized


Can you paste the screenshot of the Azure AD application API permission blade?

Any update on the issue?

To access a Function App that uses Microsoft as Identity Provider, check the below:
Create an Azure function and created a http trigger:

Add identity provider as Microsoft and create a new application:

It must look like below:

In the Microsoft Entra ID application, the redirect URL must be https://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Expose an API blade scope will be added:

You can also add API permissions to the application (optional):
User.Read permission is must

After the above setting, I tried to access http trigger https://ruk8933.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?
I am able to access successfully:


You can also make use of existing application to configure identity provider.

Now try the same in ADF and it will work with error.
Reference:
Can't get Postman to successfully authenticate against Entra/Azure AD on Azure Function - Stack Overflow by me

Is your issue resolved? Any update?
